# Django Server Error integrating Newsletter signup

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am having an issue integrating my mailchimp signup to my Django server. I am using Django as a server, then connecting it to my frontend with react native. When going to this url (http://127.0.0.1:8000/subscribe_email) I get the following error:

```
AssertionError at /subscribe_email
'MailSubscriptionAPIView' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, or override the `get_serializer_class()` method.
```

What am I doing wrong? I just want to be able to use the post method to subscribe a user.

Here's my **views.py**

```
# Mailchimp Settings
MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = settings.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY
MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER = settings.MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER
MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID = settings.MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID


class MailSubscriptionAPIView(GenericAPIView):

    def subscribe_email(email):

        mailchimp = Client()
        mailchimp.set_config({
            "api_key": MAILCHIMP_API_KEY,
            "server": MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER
        })
        member_info = {
            "email_address": email,
            "status": "subscribed",
        }
        try:
            mailchimp.lists.add_list_member(MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID, member_info)
        except ApiClientError as error:
            print(error.text)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email = request.data['email']
        MailSubscriptionAPIView.subscribe_email(email)
        return Response({
                "status_code": status.HTTP_200_OK,
                "message": "Mail added to mailchimp"
            })
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('subscribe_email', MailSubscriptionAPIView.as_view(), name= 'subscribe-email' ),
]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating a `GenricAPIView`, you should provide a serializer class.
Serializer can be used in various ways inside `GenricAPIView`, one simple example is:

```
class MailSubscriptionAPIView(GenericAPIView):
    # Here, MailSerializer is a made-up name
    # You should create a serializer class that serializes
    # the model or some custom fields that you need
    serializer_class = MailSerializer

    def subscribe_email(email):

        mailchimp = Client()
        mailchimp.set_config({
            "api_key": MAILCHIMP_API_KEY,
            "server": MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER
        })
        member_info = {
            "email_address": email,
            "status": "subscribed",
        }
        try:
            mailchimp.lists.add_list_member(MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID, member_info)
        except ApiClientError as error:
            print(error.text)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email = request.data['email']
        MailSubscriptionAPIView.subscribe_email(email)
        return Response({
                "status_code": status.HTTP_200_OK,
                "message": "Mail added to mailchimp"
            })
```

Considering that you have a model called `Mail`, Serializer class should be something like this:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

# Considering that you have a model called Mail

class MailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Mail
        fields = "__all__"
```